# How to disable navigation menu link

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, menu, rwd-theme

My magento version is 1.9 and i am using rwd theme.

I want to remove link from the menu on homepage... I tried the following stuff but it didn't work:

1. Create some folder as this path: `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
2. Copy file Navigation.php from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
3. Go to function `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`
   **Replace the code**

   ```
   $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
   $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
   $html[] = '</a>';
   ```

   **with this code**

   ```
   if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {
           $html[] = '<a href="[removed]void(0);"'.$linkClass.'>';
           $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
           $html[] = '</a>';
   } else {
           $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
           $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
           $html[] = '</a>';
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok, so you tried some stuff, but... what did happen (or didn't)? And what did you want to happen/achieve? I'm missing the actual question here, as "How to ...?", "Why ...?", "What ...?"

Comment: i want to remove link from the menu on homepage...i tried the above stuff bt it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your request correctly, you want to remove a category in your main product category structure from the main menu.

You can do this in the admin of your site `catalog->manage-categories`. Select the category you wish to hide and under the `general information` tab you have the `Include in Navigation Menu *` option that you can set to `no`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting version 1.7, the top menu is not rendered anymore using the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` block.
Instead it makes use of an event called `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` through which you can add anything to the top menu, not only categories.
The categories are added to the top menu using `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems` that calls `_addCategoriesToMenu` from the same class
In this last mentioned method you will find the configuration of the menu item:

```
        $categoryData = array(
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
        );
```

you can replace the line `'url'` with something like this:

```
'url' => ($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) ? '[removed]void(0);' : Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
```

Comment: i want remove link from menu and my magento version is 1.9 rwd theme